# DIV with 0 width and height effecting relative position of other elements

Tags: html, css

I’m trying to get a “play” icon to appear above video links on hover. To do this I am using the :before pseudo-element to add the ► character over the link. My problem is that all of the links have relative positioning and although my :before element has a width/ height of 0 it appears to be moving the links.

Adding “display:inline-block;” to the  style fixed this problem for the majority of browsers however I am still having an issue with IE/Firefox.

HTML

```
<li class="videoLinks">
    <a>
        <img src="01-poster.png">
    </a>
    <a>
        <img src="02-poster.png">
    </a><br><br>
    <a >
        <img src="03-poster.png">
    </a></li>
```

CSS

```
.videoLinks a{
    display:inline-block;
}
.videoLinks a img{
    z-index:0;
    opacity:0.7;
    border:1px solid #808080;
    margin-left:4px;
    box-shadow:2px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.videoLinks a img:hover{
    opacity:1;
    border:1px solid #ff6600;
}
    .videoLinks a:hover:before{
        z-index:5;
        position:relative; top:-12px; left:30px;
        display:inline-block; width:0px; height:0px;
        margin:0; padding:0; border:0;
        content:"\25BA";  /** "►" **/
        color:rgba(255,96,0,0.8); font-size:80px;
        text-shadow:    -1px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
                1px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
                -1px  1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
                1px  1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        pointer-events:none;
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:before elements are displayed inline by default. as you can't set width and height of inline lements you defenitely need display: inline-block or block on those elements. Just to explain why this worked...

but may i ask why you don't use position: absolute for the :before-element? so it won't have any influence on the image and you can center it on the link. display: inline-block includes a virtual space between the play-button and the image and this is what moves your images.

Comment: “:before” puts the content before the <a> not inside of so using absolute positioning will be relative to the containing div of the links rather then the links themselves. I had thought of using “:before” on the <img> tag unfortunately it turns out <img> tags do not accept the pseudo elements.

Comment: actually, `:before` puts whatever content it contains relative to the actual element (and not necessarily "before" it). So if you set `position: relative` on the element, and `position: absolute` on `:before`, you can position the pseudo-element in relation to the actual element. You can kind of think of it as a child element.

Comment: Thanks! setting position to relative for ".videoLinks a" did the trick.

Comment: a:before sets it inside of a, before any content of a (not before a!). so position:relative on a and absolute on :before will definitely do the trick